# ActiveRecord doesn't set ID of a shared model when creating a new instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant

Wasn't entirely sure how to Google this exact question but the gist is that I have several models - User belongs to an Account, Assessment belongs to an Account, User and Assessment both have account_id in their tables. Any model that initializes another model in the same account should have the same account id. This is to ensure multitenant row-based data isolation in the application.

Here is roughly what my models look like. In fact, there are many other models that `belongs_to` Account and I'd like to make sure that all the data is tied to the correct Account.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assessments

  default_scope { where(account_id: Account.current_id)}
end

class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :assessments
  cattr_accessor :current_id

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, presence: true
end
```

Why doesn't this code work?

```
user = User.first
a = user.assessment.create
a.account_id == user.account_id # a.account_id is nil so this is False
```

```
acc = Account.first
user = acc.users.first
a = user.assessment.create
a.account_id == user.account_id # a.account_id is nil so this is False
```

Am I wrong to assume that Rails should manage this for me? Is there an alternative that will help ensure that if one model creates another model and both models have an `account_id` field, the new instance will be created with the same value?

The only alternative that I can see is manually setting the account id at every object creation.

Comment: `user.assessment` does not set `account_id` because there is no link between `Assessment` and `Account` in this process. In order for `account_id` to be set you would need to set it as `user.assessment.create` will only set the `user_id`. Additionally adding `belongs_to :account` would probably make sense to add to `Assessment` to ensure at the application level that this association is being set.

Comment: A better way to handle this given your structure would likely be to remove `account_id` from `Assessment` and then in `Account` simply add `has_many :assessments, through: :users`. This makes sense since a `User` belongs to an `Account` according to your description.

Comment: But then `Assessment` would not have a foreign_key to `Account` and would potentially be visible to other accounts? i thought has_many through was for many-to-many associations?

Comment: An Account would only be able to see the assessments for its users since user and assessment were intended to have the same account_id the effect would be the same. Has many through is not the same as has and belongs to many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way for the `create` method to know anything about the `user` object. You have to pass the `account: user.account` into the method in order to create that "back association".